# Create a rapidjson::Value from a JSON string

Tags: rapidjson

I want to  create a `rapidjson::Value` from a JSON string, e.g., `[1,2,3]`. Note: this is not a complete JSON object, it's just a JSON array. In Java I can use `objectMapper.readTree("[1,2,3]")`to create a `JsonNode` from a String.

My complete C++ code is as the following:

```
#include <rapidjson/document.h>
#include <rapidjson/stringbuffer.h>
#include <rapidjson/writer.h>
#include <iostream>

// just for debug
static void print_json_value(const rapidjson::Value &value) {
    rapidjson::StringBuffer buffer;
    rapidjson::Writer<rapidjson::StringBuffer> writer(buffer);
    value.Accept(writer);

    std::cout << buffer.GetString() << std::endl;
}

//TODO: this function probably has a problem
static rapidjson::Value str_to_json(const char* json) {
    rapidjson::Document document;
    document.Parse(json);
    return std::move(document.Move());
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    const char* json_text = "[1,2,3]";

    // copy the code of str_to_json() here
    rapidjson::Document document;
    document.Parse(json_text);
    print_json_value(document);  // works

    const rapidjson::Value json_value = str_to_json(json_text);
    assert(json_value.IsArray());
    print_json_value(json_value);  // Assertion failed here

    return 0;
}
```

Could anyone find out the problem in my function `str_to_json()` ?

PS: The code above works in GCC 5.1.0 but not in Visual Studio Community 2015.

**UPDATE**:

According to the suggestion of [@Milo Yip](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1018640/milo-yip), the correct code is as the following:

```
#include <rapidjson/document.h>
#include <rapidjson/stringbuffer.h>
#include <rapidjson/writer.h>
#include <iostream>

static void print_json_value(const rapidjson::Value &value) {
    rapidjson::StringBuffer buffer;
    rapidjson::Writer<rapidjson::StringBuffer> writer(buffer);
    value.Accept(writer);

    std::cout << buffer.GetString() << std::endl;
}

static rapidjson::Document str_to_json(const char* json) {
    rapidjson::Document document;
    document.Parse(json);
    return std::move(document);
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    const char* json_text = "[1,2,3]";

    // copy the code of str_to_json() here
    rapidjson::Document document;
    document.Parse(json_text);
    print_json_value(document);  // works

    const rapidjson::Document json_value = str_to_json(json_text);
    assert(json_value.IsArray());
    print_json_value(json_value);  // Now works

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple answer: the return type should be `rapidjson::Document` instead of `rapidjson::Value`.

Longer version: A `Document` contains an allocator to store all the values during parsing. When returning the `Value` (actually the root of the tree), the local `Document` object will be destructed and the buffers in the allocator will be released. It is like `std::string s = ...; return s.c_str();` inside a function.